# Phonological process triggering <I'on't> for "I don't"

Tags: contractions, phonology, african-american-vernacular-english

Mostly in AAVE, and mainly in the sentence "**I'on't know**", e.g. [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=3RCElot_1zMC&lpg=PA73&dq=%22I'on't%20know%22&hl=es&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q=%22I'on't%20know%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=Y6dDXb5NZzMC&lpg=PA116&dq=%22I'on't%20know%22&hl=es&pg=PA116#v=onepage&q=%22I'on't%20know%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=dsXaw5WRJqoC&lpg=PA89&dq=%22I'on't%20give%22&hl=es&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=%22I'on't%20give%22&f=false),  [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=xBxCCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT32&dq=%22I%20'ONT%20EVEN%22&hl=es&pg=PT32#v=onepage&q=%22I%20'ONT%20EVEN%22&f=false), and even [y'on't](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35431403/Famous).

However, I am not aware of which process triggered such a pronunciation.

EDIT: A related pronunciation is heard for [*Why don't you* [tʃʊ]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gShUU_HKrqg)

Comment: No process triggered the pronunciation. It just is said like that.

Comment: Some Ebonics pronunciations are more unique, for instance, dropping b, d, or g at the beginning of auxiliary verbs like 'don't' and 'gonna', yielding Ah 'on know for "I don't know" and ama do it for "I'm going to do it." https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/what-ebonics-african-american-english

Comment: The reason? Less articulatory work. And even white AmE speakers do it and don't realize it.

Comment: @Lambie Likewise, final -v sounds are lost in many other words, such as give, but I do not know what phonological context triggers it: **luh** "love" as in _I Luh Ya Papi_

Comment: Please stop saying it is "triggered". That word is very misleading. It probably occurs because it is less articulatory work to say: I'ont than I **don't**. To go from I to O (produce the sound!) is less effort than to go from I to a hard D. Just as in Spanish: The Andalusians (and, for example, Cubans) typically say leave out an intervocalic D: el certificao instead of el certifica**d**o.

Comment: @Lambie then why not _I'idn't_? In Spanish -ado, can always be reduced, and there're even some fossils such **cantaor** (< -ado-)

Comment: I won't post an answer as I have not written a paper on this phenomenon. But it's pretty obvious that dropping consonants is due to it being easier to say the thing with less work of articulation.

Comment: But we do do this in English for *I'idn't*. We actually say: I'idint go today. [I really can't be bothered to write it phonetically]

Comment: cantaor and bailaor are Flamenco terms, really. But as I said, it is LESS work.